# PowerShell Import-CSV Ping Script

Tags: powershell, csv, ping

I have a .csv sheet with two columns (potentially more to be added in the future). Column A is a list of PC hostnames and column B is a list of text names for column A/B (manually added/updated) see exampled below:

```
A  B
PC1  John
PC2  Luke
PC3  Alfred
PC4  Dion
```

What I would like to do is have a PS script which imports the .csv and separates the columns into for example `$ColumnA`, `$ColumnB`. I can ping each value in `$ColumnA` and add `$ColumnB` as text in the same line, so you can tell who's PC is what. The reason behind manually having ColumnB is we won't to manually update this field rather than querying WMI etc.

Also, eventually once I have this working, I want to add more and add ColumnC with PC location. Also I want to build on the script and query more with `$ColumnA` in the near future once I have the basic working (and I understand it).

Comment: What is your question here? What does your code look like? What doesn't work as expected? For getting started [read this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/09/23/use-powershell-to-work-with-csv-formatted-text/).

Answer (score 0):

Everything in PowerShell is object, so, when you import a csv file, it will inheritate your CSV headers.

In your example :

```
$CSVvar = import-csv C:\yourCSVFile.csv -delimiter ' '
```

Write-Host $CSVvar.A :

```
PC1
PC2
PC3
PC4
```

Write-Host $CSVvar.B :

```
John
Luke
Alfred
Dion
```

Write-Host $CSVvar.B[1] :

```
Luke
```

So, if you want to test your connection on each line of column B :

```
for($i=0; $i -lt $CSVvar.length; $i++){

test-connection $CSVvar.B[$i]

}
```

Be careful with your delimiter, it can be only one character length.

Hope this helps. :)